# Traveling with newborn before Aqiqa

Tags: jinn

Salam. Is it safe to travel with a newborn before Aqiqa?
I have heard that there's a fear of Jinn as the roads and tracks taken to travel could be affected by them.

Comment: Hearsay is a bad source of knowledge! If you have any sources for such a claim it would be good if you shared them.

Comment: I agree @Medi1Saif :) Allah knows better and wants nothing but the best for us. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be fearing anyone except Allah. What's written to you and him will happen no matter what, what's not written - won't happen, so don't be afraid of anything, aqiqa is not fard (obligatory) act, so it's not obligatory for you to wait for it. But I would suggest you to check the safety of the travel you're going to make for newborns, because in some cases it's not the best idea to take a newborn for an airplane flight, if you're going by a car - check the safety of the car, the comfort of the baby and e.t.c. If you're still worried about jinns, recite the azan for a baby if you didn't do it yet, and if you did it already you can also try to search for duas for a travelling and also recite the Ayat al-Kursi and 3 last surahs of Quran (Surah Al-Ikhlas, Surah Al-Falaq, and Surah An-Nas) before starting the travel and then slightly blow on your baby.

The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: “No seeker has sought protection with anything like them. [last 3 surahs]” (Abū Dāwūd)

Aishah (r.a.) narrated that whenever the Messenger of Allah ﷺ would become sick, he would recite [the last 3 Sūrahs of the Qur’ān] and then blow over his body.

The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said, “In Sūrah al-Baqarah, there is a verse which is the best verse of the Qur’ān. It is never recited in a house except that the Shaytān leaves: it is Āyat al-Kursī” (Ḥākim).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Arzybek :) I totally agree with you.